# How do I extend react-bootstrap component using typescript?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-bootstrap

I am using `react-bootstrap@1.0.0-beta.14` and I am trying to create a custom `Button` component using react-bootstraps `Button`, adding another prop, `isLoading`.
Because of the way react-bootstrap types are defined I ended up importing some helpers types and copying a part of react-bootstrap types:

```
import React from 'react'
import { Button as Btn, ButtonProps } from 'react-bootstrap'
import { BsPrefixProps, ReplaceProps } from 'react-bootstrap/helpers'

interface Props {
  isLoading?: boolean
}

type BtnProps<As extends React.ElementType = 'button'> = ReplaceProps<
  As,
  BsPrefixProps<As> & ButtonProps
>

export const Button: React.FC<BtnProps & Props> = ({ isLoading, disabled, ...props }) => {
  return <Btn {...props} disabled={isLoading || disabled} />
}
```

This *almost* works. The error I got is telling me that `ref` prop types are wrong:

> Types of property 'ref' are incompatible.
>
> ...
>
> Type '(instance: HTMLButtonElement | null) => void' is not assignable to type '(instance: Button> | null) => void'.

I stripped most of the error message to get the relevant bit.
Do I need to wrap the component in forwardRef for this work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, I decided to solve this with a workaround:

```
export const Button: React.FC<Props & React.ButtonHTMLAttributes<HTMLButtonElement>> = 
({ isLoading, disabled, ...props }) => 
<Btn disabled={isLoading || props.disabled} {...props} />
```

This is not ideal because in theory, `Btn` can be a different native element (not always a `button`) but it's good enough for my use case.

Comment: I struggled with this exact problem for hours, without a satisfying result. Looks like your approach is the only working one, thanks for sharing.

Answer (score 4):

you can see better way of doing is at following code piece.

```
import React from 'react';
import { Button, ButtonProps } from 'react-bootstrap'

interface PropType extends ButtonProps {
    buttonText: string;
    isSubmitting: boolean;
}

export const SubmitButton: React.FC<PropType> = (props: PropType) => {
let { isSubmitting, buttonText, ...remainingProps } = props;
    return (
        <Button  variant="primary" type="submit" disabled={props.isSubmitting} style={{margin: 10}} {...remainingProps}>
            {props.buttonText}
        </Button>
    )
}
```

Comment: this won't work for the same reason this isn't working https://stackoverflow.com/a/60324501/2874705

Answer (score 1):

I know this was answered a while back, but I had a similar problem and am fairly happy I just about got to the 'right' solution. In detail it's here: https://shaderfun.com/2021/10/04/extending-boot-strap-in-type-script/

This example shows how I did it:

```
//imports
import React from "react";
import { Button, ButtonProps } from "react-bootstrap";
import { BsPrefixProps, ReplaceProps } from "react-bootstrap/helpers"
import { BsInfo } from 'react-icons/bs'

//handy type defintion to wrap up the replace+bsprefix bits of bootstrap
type BootstrapComponentProps<As extends React.ElementType, P> = ReplaceProps<As, BsPrefixProps<As> & P>

//our extended button properties
type NewButtonProps = {
    //any new properties we want to add go here
} & ButtonProps

//boot-strap-ified full button properties with all the bells and whistles
type MyInfoButtonProperties<As extends React.ElementType = 'button'> =
    BootstrapComponentProps<As, NewButtonProps>

//our button!
export function MyInfoButton<As extends React.ElementType = 'button'>(props: MyInfoButtonProperties<As>) {
    return <Button {...props} 
        variant={props.variant || "light"}>
        <BsInfo/>
    </Button>
}
```

I was aiming to create a button that defaulted to 'light' and contained the BsInfo icon from react-icons.

Answer (score 0):

I am just wondering if the following simplification would not suffice?

```
import React from 'react'
import { Button as Btn, ButtonProps } from 'react-bootstrap'

interface Props {
  isLoading?: boolean
}

export const Button: React.FC<ButtonProps & Props> = ({ isLoading, ...props }) => {
  return <Btn {...props} disabled={isLoading || props.disabled} />
}
```

Comment: not really because ButtonProps are missing all the props you would want to pass to native button element, like className, onClick etc